# Mist wallet showing no balance but nanopool showing ether in address

Tags: wallets, mining-pools

How do I eventually get the ether I have just successfully been mining or paid for by nanopool into a wallet that I can sell for USD? I wish to know why my mist wallet still contains a balance of 0.00 but my nanopool has 0.04, I am not looking to sell now of course but just wanted to know for the future so I don't lose or get stuck with ETH I cannot move. Also how does a platform like Coinbase come into play here?

Comment: Has Mist fully synced? Without a fully synced node your balance won't be up to date.

Comment: well now im getting error messages like this....

Error: invalid receipt root hash (remote: 0075ccbbecd4e4ef235e97a2cfd65f2f9d84246183024eab28b541383eb667b6 local: c43ead1e713727ee1fe38fcbbe84159d3787b770a7ebe947c65617209e4f1390)
##############################

any idea what this means?

Answer (score 2):

Nanopool has a minimum payout of 0.2ETH. This means you must mine at least that much before nanopool will deposit it into your address.

Comment: oh that makes perfect sense then. so once i hit the .2 mark is should show up in both my nanopool and my mist account.